# Why Eclipse returns an error when trying to convert an applet, while NetBeans not?

Tags: java, eclipse, javacard

Below, you see a Java Card program that acts as a 8 byte random number generator :

```
package randGen;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacard.security.RandomData;

public class RandGen extends Applet {
    byte[] generatedArray;
    RandomData randData =   RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);

    private RandGen() {
        generatedArray = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)8, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new RandGen().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        byte[] byffer = arg0.getBuffer();
        byte[] generatedRandom = MyGenerator(arg0);
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(generatedRandom, (short) 0, byffer, (short) 0,
                (short) generatedRandom.length);
        arg0.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) generatedRandom.length);
    }

    public byte[] MyGenerator(APDU apdu) {
        randData.generateData(generatedArray, (short) 0, (short) 8);
        return generatedArray;
    }

}
```

This program converts to *.cap* file successfully in NetBeans IDE, but when I wanted to do the same operation with the Eclipse IDE, it returns the below error in respond of my request for conversion the applet :

> error: randGen: empty package.

I added an image also : (As you see there is not error in the code, but the project directory marked with a red times mark as a sign of an error)

[image]

**Update :** I used **Java Card 2.2.2 SDK** and **Eclipse-JCDE 0.2** plugin to convert my program to *cap* files in Eclipse.

Any idea?

Comment: Neither NetBeans nor Eclipse contain a converter unless you install the right plugins. Please list the Java Card SDK + plugin that is used and mind your tags in the future; the error seems to be in Eclipse, right? PS sometimes you need to clean the project if the deletion of the package doesn't go right in Eclipse. If you've got McAfee installed, f*cking disable that trap first.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes,you are right, I added the complementary information to my question (JCDK2.2.2 and Eclipse-JCDE0.2). And that's weird! I delete the project and create it again and it works fine now!! May I ask you to post this tricky solution as an answer to let me check it? :) (BTW McAfee is not installed, I hate it! :D)

Comment: Unfortunately McAfee has nice enterprisy features (good management tools), and it is well recognized. This is unfortunate since it is the biggest crap out there otherwise.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes But for me, it eat voraciously all of my CPU!

Comment: That's nothing, it is able to get my SSD to < 1 MB/s from the 530 MB/s it should be able to do. OK, I'm working on security so the IT dept configured it for max protection, but still. My 8 year old linux laptop with aging Intel G2 SSD (aging but great) works about 20 times faster - if not more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes Eclipse fails to completely delete the .class files or .cap files on Windows machines, usually due to a program (e.g. McAfee or another virus scanner) locking files. In that case not all files will be deleted. In that case the right builders may not get triggered and you will get weird failures.

Those kind of errors are of course horrible to detect. Instead, if something fails uncontrollably, be sure to clean your build so Eclipse can retry. If you've changed code, first refresh, then clean (and possibly, refresh again). Anything to get the project state synced with the actual state on disk really.